# Heep, a Stack Exchange client for Windows

Tags: app

### **Heep is a Stack Exchange client for Windows.**

[image]

Available now on the Windows Store [here](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/heep/ea0205d0-2420-4aba-979b-52dc8beff27c).

**Features:**

- Browsing Stack Exchange questions based on Interesting, New, and Hot questions.
- Searching Stack Exchange questions
- Voting on questions, comments and answers
- View Stack Exchange notifications

[image]

As far as contact goes for bugs and feature requests.  This post will be a good start, I'll be setting up an official site for this later.

Comment: Is this closed source or does there exist a repository? I am interested in Windows/WindowsPhone app development and what better way to learn it than going through an existing app.

Comment: It's closed source for now. That may change in the future.

Comment: Upvoting doesn't work.